# Is there a way to run `CREATE DATABASE []` command so if the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files exists then just use those files? If don't then create new files?

Tags: sql-server

I created a windows application that installs an SQL Server 2022 Express.

When my application runs for the first time, it creates a database with `CREATE DATABASE [<database_name>]`. This creates the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files somewhere on the PC. And everything works fine.

My problem is when my app and the SQL Server Express are uninstalled, the database `.mdf` and `.ldf` files are left behind (they are not deleted). Then if I install my app again; the next time my app runs for the first time, I get an error

> Database '<database_name>' already exists. Choose a different database name.

This error is because my app runs the `CREATE DATABASE [<database_name>]` command thinking is a new fresh installation.

Is there a way to run `CREATE DATABASE [<database_name>]` command so if the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files exist, then just use those files? If they don't exist, then create new files?

If possible, I would like to use the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files again if they are already there. But I'm okay starting fresh if it is easy.

I know I could use something like these commands:

```
CREATE DATABASE [<database_name>]
[ON  [PRIMARY] ( FILENAME = N'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\DBNAME_Data.MDF')]
[FOR ATTACH]
```

But the problem is that I don't know the path of those `.mdf` and `.ldf` files.

Comment: Imo just backup your data and restore on recreation of database. So it becomes a controllable process.

Comment: Why don't you just drop the database before uninstalling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If database has created with default parameters - files will be created in default data locations.

You can check it on Sql Managemenet Studio in database settings.

[image]

Or retrieve path from SERVERPROPERTY function (works MSSQL 2016 or above):

```
SELECT
  SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath') AS InstanceDefaultDataPath,
  SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath') AS InstanceDefaultLogPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Arkee.  Your answer really helped.  I first check if the database files exist.  If they exist, I attach the files to the Server; if they don't, then I run the `CREATE DATABASE` command (Without the `FOR ATTACH`).

This is the final C# fix using your `SERVERPROPERTY` function:

```
string DB_ConnectionString = "Data Source=<ComputerName>;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=<1234>";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DB_ConnectionString))
{       
    // Check if we have database files from a previous installation
    string sql = "SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath') AS InstanceDefaultDataPath";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

    connection.Open();
    string mdfFilePath = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath') AS InstanceDefaultLogPath";
    string ldfFilePath = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    connection.Close();

    if (File.Exists(mdfFilePath + "\\MyAwesomeDatabase.mdf"))
    {           
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE [MyAwesomeDatabase]" +
                              "ON  PRIMARY ( NAME = N'MyAwesomeDatabase_Data', FILENAME = N'" + mdfFilePath + "MyAwesomeDatabase.mdf')" +
                              "LOG ON ( NAME = N'MyAwesomeDatabase_Log', FILENAME = N'" + ldfFilePath + "MyAwesomeDatabase_Log.LDF')" +
                              "FOR ATTACH";
            string rtn = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Database Files", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Create Database with the CREATE DATABASE [<database_name>] command since there are not previous database files
    }
}
```